# How to verify Jedis connection before read?

Tags: redis, jedis

I have a service that uses jedis to read from redis. Obviously I don't intend to establish a new connection with every GET request but curious on the guard rails i need in case read fails because of connection failures ? To clean up idle connections i have configured `timeout` on server side. Reference [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/unstable/redis.conf)

Can some jedis/redis experts here recommend me the ideal way keeping latency in mind. I can think of the following, if there is any better way, please suggest

1. If read fails due to connection failure, try to establish connection
   again and then read again.
2. Before every read, verify
   `jedis.isBroken()` or `jedis.isConnected()`. Should i verify both or either would suffice ?
3. Do `jedis.ping()` and on success only read , else try re-establish the connection.

Answer (score 2):

nodejs with use ioredis package

```
function connect() {

  let isConnected = false

  redis = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL)

  redis.on('connect', async (err) => {
    console.log('Redis Connected')
    isConnected = true
  })
  
  redis.on('error', async (err) => {
    console.log(err)
    isConnected = false
  })
}
```

You can know like this

Comment: It's not about the first connection. Let's say i establish a connection, and using it for few hours. After 12 hours says due to stale connection or network error if READ fails, how do I validate it is my question.

Comment: You need to know connection dead before READ.

Comment: Ya , exactly. What is the right way to determine if the connection is dead ?

Comment: if you use ioredis, you can check package from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis

Comment: i need for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JedisPool`<sup>a</sup> or `JedisPooled`<sup>b</sup> and forget the hassles of connection management. This will cover your (1) and (2).

For (3), you can use `GenericObjectPoolConfig#setTestOnBorrow(true)`. Both JedisPool<sup>c</sup> and JedisPooled<sup>d</sup> accepts a GenericObjectPoolConfig in some of their constructors.

[a] JedisPool is available since very long time ago.
[b] JedisPooled is available since version 4.0.0.
[c] It is `GenericObjectPoolConfig<Jedis>` for JedisPool.
[d] It is `GenericObjectPoolConfig<Connection>` for JedisPooled.

---

An example with JedisPooled:

```
  GenericObjectPoolConfig<Connection> poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig<>();
  poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);

  HostAndPort hostAndPort = new HostAndPort(HOST, PORT);   // server host and port

  JedisClientConfig clientConfig = DefaultJedisClientConfig.builder()
      .timeoutMillis(TIMEOUT)           // set your preferred timeout
      .user(USERNAME)                   // server username, if any
      .password(PASSWORD)               // server password (for that user)
      .build();

  JedisPooled jedis = new JedisPooled(poolConfig, hostAndPort, clientConfig);

  jedis.sadd("planets", "Venus");       // just example
  jedis.sadd("planets", "Mars");        // just example

  jedis.close();
```

Comment: Is JedisPooled applicable for Redis Cluster?